# how to disable auto focus on google maps InfoBubble?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to disable the map autofocus operation when I open a new `InfoBubble` window `(InfoBubble.open())` on **google maps**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

set the `disableAutoPan` to true on the `infobuble` option.

**Code:**

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        map: map,
        disableAutoPan: true
    });
```